# extract list inside a list as a single list

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I've a two POJOs, 
Sample code below

```
class A {
    String name;
    Object entries; // this can be a List<String> or a string - hence Object datatype
   //getters and setter here
}

class B {
    int snumber;
    List<A> values;
   //getters and setters here
}
```

Controller class

```
class ControllerA {
    public getList(B b) {
        List<String> list = b.getValues().stream.map(e -> e.getEntries()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

This returns me a list of the list:

```
[[12345, 09876], [567890, 43215]]
```

but what I want is a single list like

```
[12345,09876,567890, 43215]
```

How can I do that with Java 8 streams?

I've tried `flatMap` also, but that doesn't go well with the `Object` datatype of entries.

Comment: `Object entries; // this can be a list or a string - hence Object datatype` - this is terrible practice.  Polymorphism sounds like a much better idea, and should make your life easier here.

Comment: How can I make it better? `List<String> entries`?

Comment: @user2340345 this depends on your context. *this can be a list or a string* -> if it's a single String make it a List of a single element; if it's a list of multiple strings make it as such.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider a `List<String>` as a field `entries` in the `A` class.

As [@Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene) mentioned in the comments,

> If it's a single String make it a `List` of a single element; if it's a list of multiple strings make it as such.

Working with a collection of a single type can simplify the process:

```
b.getValues()                           // -> List<A>
        .stream()                       // -> Stream<A>
        .map(A::getEntries)             // -> Stream<List<String>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)    // -> Stream<String>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());  // -> List<String>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! :)
Can also do with lambda for flatMap - `s -> s.stream()`

Comment: @user2340345, the method reference `Collection::stream` is a shortcut for `s -> s.stream()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it too.

```
b.getValues()                   // -> List<A>
    .stream()                   // -> Stream<A>
    .map(A::getEntries)         // -> Stream<List<String>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)// -> Stream<String>
    .toList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).